# How to trim input in rails models globally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails app there are several models where users are posting data to the database. Lots of this data has trailing and leading whitespaces. Is there a way I can globally strip all input's leading and trailing whitespaces?

I'd like to avoid doing this for every field in every model, seems like there could be a global way to handle this during a `before_save`.

Any used techniques out there?

Thanks

Comment: you could override `to_s` function

Comment: Holy Hand Grenades, apneadiving, that's quite excessive. Let's stick to less destructive methods that allow for sane debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one simple way to do it on selected attributes:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Acts
    module AttributeAutoStripper
      def self.included(base)
        base.extend(ClassMethods)
      end

      module ClassMethods
        def acts_as_attribute_auto_stripper (*names)
          class_eval <<-EOV
            include ActiveRecord::Acts::AttributeAutoStripper::InstanceMethods
            before_validation :auto_strip_selected_attributes
            def auto_strip_attributes
              #{names.inspect}
            end
          EOV
        end
      end
      module InstanceMethods
        def auto_strip_selected_attributes
          if auto_strip_attributes
            auto_strip_attributes.each do |attr_name|
              self.send("#{attr_name}=", self.send(attr_name).to_s.strip) unless self.send(attr_name).blank?
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ActiveRecord::Acts::AttributeAutoStripper
```

and then in your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_attribute_auto_stripper :name, :email
end
```

Answer (score 4):

One more gem to do this job: https://github.com/holli/auto_strip_attributes

Also in some cases you want to squish the data user has inputted to get rid of multiple spaces inside the variable. E.g. with names or nicks.

```
gem "auto_strip_attributes", "~> 1.0"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  auto_strip_attributes :name, :nick, :nullify => false, :squish => true
end
```

All the gems and other approaches work a bit the same way by using before_save callback. (Code example is in Jeremys example.) So there might be some issues with custom setters. You can choose to do it with

```
attributes.each do before_validation do ...
  record.send("#{attr_name}=", record.send(attr_name).to_s.strip)
```

or with

```
attributes.each do before_validation do ...
  record[attribute] = record.send(attr_name).to_s.strip)
```

First approach will call setter twice (once when setting, once in before_validation). The second will call setter only once but will alter the data after the call to setter.

Answer (score 0):

If users are posting data to the DB through a form, you could create a before filter method that'll strip the parameters. Put that in the Application controller.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This fork of the StripAttributes plugin may do the trick for you:

https://github.com/fragility/strip_attributes

Answer (score 0):

You could create an ActiveRecord subclass with a before_save filter that strips all attributes. Then, make all of your models a subclass of this new class.